# How to stub zendesk_api current_user for a spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a model method which I am trying to write a spec for. The method is like this:

```
def my_method
   puts current_user.user_attirbute
end
```

Where `current_user` is provided by an authentication gem, `zendesk_api-1.14.4`. To make this method testable, I changed it to this:

```
def my_method(user_attribute = nil)
   if user_attribute = nil
      user_attribute = current_user.user_attribute
   end 
   puts user_attribute
end
```

This refactor works and is testable, but doesn't seem like a good practice. Ideally the gem would provide some sort of test helper to help stub/mock the `current_user`, but I haven't been able to find anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please explain what is current_user and how is zendesk_api is related to it? And where is `my_method` is defined?

Comment: @intale. `my_method` is a member of an `ActiveRecord` model class. I updated the post to reflect this. `current_user` is a a method exposed by a class in the zendesk gem `zendesk_api-1.14.4/lib/zendesk_api/client.rb#current_user(boolean)`. sorry for the poor explanations, this is somewhat blackbox-ish for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go simple way and just test returning of proper value by `current_user#user_attribute` method. Example:

```rb
describe '#my_method' do 
  subject { instance.my_method } # instance is an instance of your class where #my_method is defined

  let(:user) { instance_spy(ZendeskAPI::User, user_attribute: attr) }
  let(:attr} { 'some-value' }

  before do
    allow(instance).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
  end 

  it { is_expected.to eq(attr) }
end
```

But I would go with VCR cassette(vcr gem is [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/vcr)) because it is related 3rd party API response - to minimize a risk of false positive result. Next example demonstrates testing with recorded response(only in case if #current_user method performs a request to zendesk):

```rb
describe '#my_method', vcr: { cassette_name: 'zendesk_current_user' } do 
  subject { instance.my_method } 

  it { is_expected.to eq(user_attribute_value) } # You can find the value of user_attribute_value in recorded cassette
end
```

P.S. I assumed that you put `puts` in your method for debugging. If it is intentional and it is part of the logic - replace `eq` with `output` in my example.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. I think VCR makes sense, but I don't understand how to record the response (when I run my spec with your sample code, `current_user` is still undefined). `curent_user` is a method in zendesk's client.rb, `lib/zendesk_api/client.rb#current_user`. Any suggestions how I can use VCR to mock `client#current_user`?

Comment: You don’t need to mock it. You should allow your code to perform real request to zendesk. Please read carefully what vcr is and how to use it. If it is still unclear - use my first suggestion.